# How to download and install third party programs using Python

Tags: python, operating-system, python-requests

I got a task from my teacher to make a programm that should do following things:

1. It should find a download url of offline installer of any product (for example Google Chrome);
2. Find what is the latest version of the product;
3. Then silently (without user interaction) install Chrome;
4. Show keys of silent installation for this program (absolutely have no idea what does this mean);
5. And then check if installation was successful.

And so I googled how to download something using python and found a lot of information, and I guess I will do this using requests library (if you have any other suggestion or ideas it would be great). But the problem is that I don't know what is the best way to find the needed download URL.
Also I googled how to "silently" install program and I can do it this way:

```
 import os

 os.system('start path_to_downloaded_exe_file /s')
```

If you have any other suggestion or ideas it ALSO would be great! And by the "keys of silent installation" teacher implies "/s" I guess. I bet there should be some more keys.

But I legit have no idea how to check if installation was successful.

Any ideas? Thank you!